# Is it harmless to call GC.SuppressFinalize within the finalizer?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, finalizer

Because the `finalizer/IDisposable` and so-called "`IDisposable` pattern" topic tends to bring out lots of posturing, pontificating, and militant opinion (*not*-respectively, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344293/calling-gc-suppressfinalize-from-within-a-finalizer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605412/why-should-we-call-suppressfinalize-when-we-dont-have-a-destructor), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694725/is-it-appropriate-to-call-gc-collect-in-a-finalizer), and more), I really hesitate to ask this. Hoping to preempt those well-worn debates, I'm keeping to a very simple question which doesn't appear to have a concise answer on StackOverflow...

Is calling `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` vacuous once the object's finalizer has begun executing? More specifically or usefully (of course), is it harmless to call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` from within the finalizer itself? (Again, we're not debating any "why" here)

So in other words, beyond the overhead for calling the API and its duly setting a flag in the object header, are there any bad, unwanted, or otherwise tangible correctness or performance effects?

Comment: `Is calling GC.SuppressFinalize(this) vacuous once the object's finalizer has begun executing?` - according to the wording in the [Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), yes. Still, [according to the IDisposable pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/898867/11683), that is not the place to put `GC.SuppressFinalize` to begin with.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, and you're right it *is* a matter of ***wording*** in that docs excerpt, I guess I was hoping to nail it down more definitively. As for that so-called "pattern." I was trying to discourage that sort of bait here...

Comment: If it's in the docs, then that's the definitive answer. If you hit a problem while doing what the docs say, then Microsoft will take it as a bug (they may not fix it, but GC & finalization are important things). The dispose pattern has been well documented since forever-I'm surprised there's controversy. That said, are you sure you need a finalizer? Has you read all the things a finalizer can't do? The need to write a finalizer is rare and writing a solid one is hard.

Comment: Its just a flag in the object, if used for its intended purposes will have no appreciable overhead (in-fact its an optimization of sorts (term used loosely) for the GC and has a very specific purpose), DO you need to flag that no finalization is needed or all unmanaged code has been cleaned up?. Calling the `SuppressFinalize` once the *finalizer* has begun seems suspicious, and its not its intended use case and contrary to its goal in life. As we know (and i am sure you do) Finalizers/Destructors are a very heated topic, because there is virtually no use case for them

Comment: @Flydog57 The issue is that the docs don't quite answer the question exactly. It says, "If *obj* does not have a finalizer, the call to the `SuppressFinalize` method has no effect." This does not conclusively entail that `SuppressFinalize` has no effect on objects that ***do*** have a finalizer.

Comment: It has no affect because the GC doesnt need to call the finalizer and is probably optimized out anyway

Comment: @TheGeneral Ah, you're responding to my previous remark about the docs. Anyway, the presumed use case here would be a GC object that **only** ever needs native cleanup, *i.e.*, never has any managed cleanup to do, and that thus would indeed have a finalizer.

Comment: @TheGeneral I took it as obvious that calling `SuppressFinalize` under finalization would be "redundant" (note: different from "vacuous"), and certainly nobody would expect an extraneous ***Suppress***Finalize call to trigger multiple, or excess, finalizations. While those two assumptions do narrow down the relevant use cases even further, technically they don't go quite so far as making any particular `SuppressFinalize` call "not make sense." For example, the call could originate in a method that is shared between both finalizer and non-finalizer code paths...

Answer (score 4):

Of course, it would be much better to avoid the finalizer altogether, and use `SafeHandle`, as the modern idiom dictates. Then all of this stuff about finalizers becomes completely moot.

That said, the wisdom of doing so notwithstanding, it is perfectly safe to call `GC.SuppressFinalize()` from the finalizer. [The documentation for the method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) describes what the method does:

> This method sets a bit in the object header of obj, which the runtime checks when calling finalizers.

The runtime may actually check this bit during a GC operation as well, which is when on finding an object unreachable, that object's finalizer would be put into the finalizer queue. If it's set at that point, finalizer doesn't even wind up in the queue.

Checking it again later, before calling the finalizer itself, also allows finalization of the object to be avoided, if it turns out that some other object's finalizer wound up disposing it even though the that object's finalizer was put in the finalization queue.

Both of these checks occur before the finalizer is called. Once the finalizer is called, the bit in the object has no purpose. Setting it is harmless, but won't accomplish anything.

*As an aside: note that past implementations of .NET used `Finalizer` and `FReachable` queues. When an object was created, if it had a finalizer, it would be moved to the `Finalizer` queue. Once the object was unreachable, it would be moved to the `FReachable` queue for later finalization. Calling `SuppressFinalize()` would remove the object from the `Finalizer` queue. By the time the finalizer runs, the object is no longer in this queue, so the `SuppressFinalize()` call would be a NOP, similarly harmless.*

Now, that said, your question is broad: *"…are there any bad, unwanted, or otherwise tangible correctness or performance effects?"*. Much of that is in the eye of the beholder. I would argue that a finalizer that calls `GC.SuppressFinalize()` is incorrect. So, that would be a "tangible correctness effect" to me. I also find code that deviates from published, acknowledged standard patterns to be "unwanted". Without more specific criteria in the question to constrain it, the answer to that part of the question could be any of "yes", "no", "sometimes", etc.

There is in fact a duplicate question to yours, but no one's deigned to answer it: [Calling GC.SuppressFinalize() from within a finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36344293). I do find the thread of comments on point though, especially Eric Lippert's contributions:

> Your supposition is that the unnecessary call to SuppressFinalize is the error in your plan. That's not the problem; the problem is the disposal of *managed* resources on the finalizer thread. Recall to your mind that finalizers run on their own thread, and that managed resources can be thread-affinitized, and now start to imagine the horrors that could result. Moreover: finalizers run in arbitrary order. A managed object disposed on the finalizer thread might have already been finalized; now you are possibly running finalization logic twice on one object; is it robust to that scenario? – Eric Lippert Mar 31 '16 at 21:58
>   1
>
> Writing a correct finalizer is extraordinarily difficult and I recommend against you trying ever, ideally, but definitely hold off until you understand the pattern better. If you are not sufficiently scared yet, my series of articles on the subject might put more fear into you: [ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/…](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/) – Eric Lippert Mar 31 '16 at 21:59
>
> …
>
> @Tom: The question is "I'm using the dispose pattern completely wrong; is this particular part of what I'm doing wrong?" *No, the whole thing is wrong from the very first sentence*. You don't use Dispose to dispose managed resources, and you certainly don't use a finalizer for that. That's the problem here. Is there anything wrong, per se, with calling SuppressFinalize from a finalizer? Well, it will work, but *there should not be a situation in which that is the correct thing to do*, so whether it works or not should be irrelevant. – Eric Lippert Jul 7 at 14:17
>
> @Tom: Also, why do you call SuppressFinalize in the first place? Only because it is a performance optimization. But under what circumstances is it an optimization *when called from the finalizer thread?* Only when you've *failed* to make that optimization from the main thread! That's the place to do that optimization! – Eric Lippert Jul 7 at 14:24

IMHO, these comments bring the primary issue to a fine point: asking whether it's safe to call `SuppressFinalize()` from the finalizer is the wrong question. If you've gotten as far as having to ask that question, the code is already wrong, and the answer to the question is probably not all that relevant. The right approach is to fix the code so you don't have to ask that question.

Finally, while not exactly the same issue, I think it's also worth pointing out that the usual guidance to call `SuppressFinalize()` at the end of the `Dispose()` method is probably incorrect. If called, it should be called at the *beginning* of the `Dispose()` method. See [Be Careful Where You Put GC.SuppressFinalize](https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2018/02/08/be-careful-where-you-put-gc-suppressfinalize/)

Comment: Nice answer, and very verbose, plus one

Comment: I agree, excellent write-up. And as [hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044679/is-it-harmless-to-call-gc-suppressfinalize-within-the-finalizer#comment102490144_58044679) in a comment on the question, the only possible quibble is stylistic/philosophical, namely your well-stated and fully-entitled preference for adhering to standard patterns perhaps to the exclusion of maximizing DRY code-sharing. But again, let's all agree not to go there... So yes, we're all good.

Answer (score 2):

In short, it's rare to use a *Finalizer*, you should be cleaning up your application deterministically. Also there are race conditions are other reasons why *finalization* in *.net* is problematic {insert huge blog posts and a long lists of recommendations here}.

<sub>*When you do want a finalizer, you want it in addition to a `Dispose`, not instead of `Dispose`.*</sub>

In most use cases, if you were to use a *finalizer*, you would call the `SuppressFinalize` in your *Dispose* method, but to answer the question (and others)

> Is calling GC.SuppressFinalize(this) vacuous once the object's
>   finalizer has begun executing?

The call to `SuppressFinalize` is actually quite trivial, it just sets a flag in the object to prevent it being added to the finalize queue. It has little *overhead* in and of itself, and can be set in any code path. This will likely not be your problem.

However, the real problem here is preventing the *GC* from *finalizing* and your object *disposing* at the same time, and assumptions about the state of the system around you during their execution.

To try and mitigate this, you would call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` as soon as you can, use a flag to determine if you have disposed. or even check if the *appdomain* or the *environment* has started to unload or shut down

```
if (!Environment.HasShutdownStarted && !AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload())
```

Either way there is still a race condition and problems here, and mitigating or dealing with them will depend on exactly why you need the *finalizer* and what you are trying to clean up and how.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that it's unwise to wade into any GC race potential, so a better strategy that I use is to always deploy (lock-free) atomic guaranteed code on each of the object's ***own*** data fields, typically ***within*** both (or either) the `Dispose()` or finalizer methods, as appropriate. It's as bulletproof as possible that way regardless of how either method gets called when or by whom or how many times, or reentrantly, and really not that hard to do. And yes the finalizer might never get called, so it must really only be viewed as a "good citizen" cleanup attempt.

Comment: "When you do want a finalizer, you want it *in addition* to Dispose, *not instead of* Dispose."  Great rule, always true. +1